# Running a segue after selecting a table once a Asynchronous request is finished

Tags: ios, json

I'm trying to run a url request to get a JSON file after a certain table row is selected, based on the row a unique ID is sent with the URL request and a different JSON is generated.  Here is my prepareforSegue

```
    // MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
     // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    var divisionScene = segue.destinationViewController as! DivisionViewController

    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {
    let arrayIndex = indexPath.row
       //println("Index: \(arrayIndex)")

        torneoIDTransfer = torneos[arrayIndex].torneoID
        //println("\(torneoIDTransfer)")


        //check second url with second request type same token
        //sets url to string using token
        let tercerURL = NSURL(string: "http://api.zione.mx/get.json.asp?tr=3&tkn=\(tkn)&tor=\(torneoIDTransfer)")

        //initializes request

        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: tercerURL!)
        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.currentQueue()) { response, jsonDataRequest3, error in
            let dataRequest3 = jsonDataRequest3

            //takes data, saves it as json
            let tercerJSON = JSON(data: jsonDataRequest3)

            //checks to see that contents != nil, meaning the JSON file was found
            if tercerJSON != nil {

                //checks amount of tournaments available in order to generate table.
                let divisionCount = tercerJSON["lista-divisiones"].count
                //sets global variable numero de torneos
                numeroDeDivisiones = divisionCount


                //for loop to go insert into Torneo nuevo each ID and name by using count from above
                for var index = 0; index < divisionCount; ++index {
                    var divisionID = Int(tercerJSON["lista-divisiones" ][index]["DivisionID"].number!)
                    var nomDivision = tercerJSON["lista-divisiones"][index]["nomDivision"].string
                    //println("\(divisionID)")
                    //println("\(nomDivision)")
                    var divisionNuevo = listaDivisiones(divisionID: divisionID, nomDivision: nomDivision!)
                    divisiones.append(divisionNuevo)
                    numeroDeDivisiones = 10
                    print("WHO IS FIRST")
                }
            }
            print("\(divisiones[0].nomDivision)")
        }
    }
}
```

And I created my segway by dragging from the table cell to the new view Controller.  However when I click the table cell the transition occurs instantly, before the request has a chance to finish and as a result no data is displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be ideal to fetch and process the data in the background, long before the user ever selects a table row. If this is not possible, then I would suggest having your destination view controller do the URL request. The URL request happens asynchronously, so it will never have a chance to finish before your source view controller is deallocated.

In your source view controller, modify `prepareForSegue`

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    var divisionScene = segue.destinationViewController as! DivisionViewController

    if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {
        let arrayIndex = indexPath.row

        torneoIDTransfer = torneos[arrayIndex].torneoID

        let tercerURL = NSURL(string: "http://api.zione.mx/get.json.asp?tr=3&tkn=\(tkn)&tor=\(torneoIDTransfer)")

        divisionScene.fetchDataAtURL(tercerURL)
    }
}
```

You'll need to define a method inside your destination view controller to handle the fetching.

```
func fetchDataAtURL(URL: NSURL) {
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: tercerURL!)
    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest( // ... your fetching logic here
}
```

You'll also need some logic to display the data once it arrives. I would suggest putting it into your request's completion callback (or rather, having the callback trigger a display update). If your `divisionScene` is a tableView, you might be able to call `reloadData` (after you update the data source). If not, you'll need some other way to update the UI. If you are updating the UI, make sure to `dispatch` to the main queue for that part.

Doing this way at least passes the URL loading responsibility to the destination view controller, which will at least be around when the data finally gets there.

Comment: Would you happen to know why my didSelectRowAtIndexPath is not working?  


    `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("divisionTableReady", sender: tableView)
    }`  




I'm going to try and run everything that I was doing in the prepareForSegue in the didSelectRow.. but am having trouble getting it to respond.

Comment: I would be happy to look at it, but I can't really tell anything from the small line of code you have in your comment. Could you open a new question with it?

Answer (score 1):

> > " the transition occurs instantly, before the request has a chance to finish".

Of course it does, that is exactly what asynchronous means. You make a point of mentioning it is asynchronous but you must have a misunderstanding about what that means. Explain what you think it means and what you expected your code to so so that you can be better educated by us.

When you call sendAsynchronousRequest() think of your program as branching into two (actually that is what does effectively happen). One part is your original code which will continue to execute i.e your prepareFoSegue code will continue to execute.
Meanwhile, in parallel, the OS will execute the request, and when the request has finished the code in the block that you passed to sendAsynchronousRequest() will be executed. Therefore your prepareForSeque() function will finish before the Json has been received.

But apart from all that, you should not be attempting or hoping or wanting the JSon to be fetched before the segue transition - to do this would halt your ui. Suppose sendAsynchronousRequest() was instead sendSynchronousRequest() and it took 10 seconds to complete, what do you think the consequence would be on your app when it runs?

You should either fetch your data a long time before you GUI is ready to display it, or if that is not possible, display your GUI immediately with no data and then update it as the data arrives.

Comment: I was trying to do that initially, the problem I was running into was that didSelectRowAtIndexPath was not allowing me to fetch the JSON based on the row I selected.  So I instead opted for fetching it in the prepareForSegue.

`func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        println("ROW WAS SELECTED")
        performSegueWithIdentifier("divisionTableReady", sender: nil)
    }`

For example when I select a table row, not even the println statment runs and I am unsure of why.